# Shared API User

Tags: apex, api, integration, salesforce-id

We have a need to have external systems integrate into our SalesCloud. For that we will need to create a User for them that would be able to connect through API to insert, update, delete data. We do not have a lot of budget for additional user licenses so I was wondering, could we create one user for multiple integrations (External system A and External System B) ? I know there are API limits per user but are there other considerations (e.g. token refreshes) that we need to consider ? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

This is a pretty common approach on small instances (and some large ones too). I usually name the user "Integration User"; some orgs call it "System" or something like that.

It's useful to have this user on a profile with API Only set, and no password expiration. If you do have to reset the password, you'll have to reconfigure those integrations that aren't connecting with OAuth. You can have more than one integration connected to the user at at the same time regardless of whether they are OAuth or username/password, although the former is preferable for both maintenance and security.

You may also want to lock this profile down based on what the integrations need to see/touch. If it's going to be the owner of a lot of data, you need to be aware of [ownership data skew](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_group_membership_data_skew.htm) and follow the recommendations about placing the user in your role hierarchy:

> If you do have a compelling reason for assigning ownership to a small number of users, you can minimize possible performance impacts by not assigning the user(s) to a role.
>
> If the user(s) must have a role to share data, we recommend that you:
>
> - Place them in a separate role at the top of the hierarchy
> - Not move them out of that top-level role
> - Keep them out of public groups that could be used as the source for sharing rules

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can share a user across multiple integrations. However, do be aware that the [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) do outline a few special limitations. For example, there is a limit of 50 concurrent query cursors. This means that if more than 50 queries are executed in a short period of time, old query cursors may expire before all the data is read. Note that this also means that you should avoid writing integrations that make a large number of concurrent requests at once. As long as your needs are modest, there's no problem sharing one integration user across several integrated systems.

Answer (score 4):

One important consideration when sharing a user account across multiple API integrations:

**Don't explicitly call the `logout` method.**

It will end all the sessions for the current user. Depending on how the sessions are established it will likely require all the other integrations to reestablish a valid session.

If the session ID is unique to the integration instead look at using [`invalidateSessions`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_invalidatesessions.htm).

Answer (score 0):

All great answers! My two cents is to have each integration use a different connected app. That will provide a means to "shut off" a single integration by deleting that one connected app, while leaving the other integrations running. It also offers a level of reporting.

Ideally, using a different integration User is desirable, but different connected apps costs much less.